# Why is that code inside => { } needs a return and the content inside => doesn't?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm relatively new to Ecmascript 6. Recently, I made a discovery. I could turn this fetch function:

```
store.fetchList = () => {
  const Document = Parse.Object.extend('Document')
  const query = new Parse.Query(Document)
  return query.find().then((results) => {
    return _.map(results, (result) => {
      return result.toJSON()
    })
  })
}
```

into this (needing only the first return if removing the curly braces):

```
store.fetchList = () => {
  const Document = Parse.Object.extend('Document')
  const query = new Parse.Query(Document)
  return query.find().then((results) =>
    _.map(results, (result) =>
      result.toJSON()
    )
  )
}
```

Why is this? And what would be the Ecmascript 5 version?

Comment: Because that's the spec. Any discussion of arrow functions would cover this. From the MDN page: *Arrow functions can have either a "concise body" or the usual "block body". The block body form doesn't automatically return a value. You need to use an explicit return statement.* If you're asking **why** that's the spec, you'd have to ask the committee members or review the minutes of their deliberations.

Answer (score 4):

If the arrow functions have only one expression, then

1. You don't need to create a function body
2. the value of that expression is returned by default.

> And what would be the JavaScript version?

ECMAScript 6 is JavaScript. If you meant to ask for the ECMAScript 5 equivalent, then there is no equivalent for this.

---

If there is more than one expression, then

1. we need to enclose them within `{` and `}`, basically we need to create a block (function body).
2. and we need to explicitly return the value.

---

If we look at the ES 6 specification for Arrow functions, we find the grammar in [this section](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions)

> ```
> ArrowFunction[In, Yield] :
>
>    ArrowParameters[?Yield] [no LineTerminator here] => ConciseBody[?In]
>
> ConciseBody[In] :
>
>    [lookahead ≠ { ] AssignmentExpression[?In]
>
>    { FunctionBody }
> ```

As we see here, you can either use `{ FunctionBody }` form, or the `AssignmentExpression` form (where you don't have `{` and `}`). But if you use the `FunctionBody` form, you need to explicitly return the value.

Answer (score 2):

Note that both

```
(result) => {
  return result.toJSON()
}
```

And

```
(result) =>
  result.toJSON()
```

Would be written as:

```
(function(result) {
    return result.toJSON();
}).bind(this)
```

In ES5.